# What good is -CSDA specified only on the shebang line?

Tags: perl, unicode, shebang

I am looking for someone to authoritatively confirm or correct what I think I know about the `-CSDA` option on the shebang line of a Perl script.

See [perldoc perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) for the documentation of `-CSDA`. Briefly

> - S: `STDIN`, `STDOUT` and `STDERR` are assumed to be in UTF-8
> - D: UTF-8 is the default PerlIO layer for both input and output streams
> - A: @ARGV elements are expected to be strings encoded in UTF-8

- For `-CSDA` to have any effect, it must be specified on the command line as in `perl -CSDA script.pl`.
- Prior to 5.10, `-CSDA` on the shebang line would silently fail because the standard streams would have already been opened and `@ARGV` already populated by the time it was encountered unless `-CSDA` was already specified on the command line as well.
- After 5.10, `-CSDA` which appears only on the shebang line causes `perl` to croak because of that problem.
- A script with `-CSDA` that used to work with `perl`s pre-5.10 should have the `-CSDA` removed from the shebang line because it was never invoked with those options on the command line (and the options, if specified solely on the shebang line, did nothing).

I would love to get some solid feedback on which of my assumptions above are wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure how authoritative I am, but I know how this works.

- Your first assumption is almost accurate. For the SDA options to have any effect, they must be present when the interpreter is started. That could be due to -CSDA on the command line, or it could be due to the PERL_UNICODE environment variable, or possibly some other method I am unaware of.
- Your second assumption is correct, at least for 5.8.8. Note that the D flag would still have had its normal effect for streams opened by the script.
- Your third assumption is correct. However, starting with 5.10.1 it will not croak if the appropriate flags are enabled via the PERL_UNICODE environment variable or some other mechanism.
- Your fourth assumption is *not* generally correct. I guess you are referring the situation when the script is invoked directly, rather than invoking the perl interpreter with the script as an argument. There are two general cases.

  - On a system where the operating system determines that any file with the extension ".pl" will be passed to the perl interpreter for execution, like Windows, you may be correct. But it could be argued that the script croaking when invoked without -CSDA is the desired behavior, rather than things mysteriously failing because the standard input and @ARGV are not UTF-8 as the script expects.
  - On a system that reads the shebang line when a script is directly executed, like most *nix shells, the command line options specified in the shebang line will be used when invoking the interpreter and therefore the -CSDA on the shebang line *will* be honored.

Comment: +1. For the last item, on systems where `/usr/bin/perl` is not the interpreter but is a program that decides which version of `perl` to invoke (say, as on OS X systems where `5.8` and `5.10` co-exist), `-CSDA` on the shebang line causes `perl` to croak when it is eventually invoked.

Comment: Were that true, it would be a bug in the wrapper script. But when I checked it on a Mac, I found that the problem is actually that 5.10.0 (which comes with OS X 10.6.6) disallows -C always, while 5.10.1 (which is what I have on my Linux machine) allows it if the specified flags are already active. Specifying perl5.8.9 on the shebang does honor -CSDA correctly.

Answer (score 3):

If your script is

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -CSDA
```

and you start your script using

```
./script foo
```

The OS will launch Perl as follows:

```
/usr/bin/perl -CSDA ./script foo
```

The change in behaviour only comes into play if launch the script incorrectly, such as by  using

```
/usr/bin/perl ./script foo
```

The fix isn't to remove `-CSDA`, the fix is to call the script correctly.

Comment: Depends. I am trying to figure out if `-CSDA` ever had any effect on the functioning of this program which I am trying to understand.

Comment: @Sinan Ünür, Do you print to STDOUT or STDERR? Do you read from STDIN? Then if you expect to deal with anything outside the ASCII range, then you should be using it or something equivalent.

Comment: Yeah, well, I don't know and that's part of the problem.